# Discord JS add role by reaction command doesn't work after restart

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a "add role by reaction" command. So when a member reacts to a specific message, the member gets a role. It actually works but when I restart my bot, it doesn't add a role anymore. Can anyone help?

here the code:

```
bot.on('message', msg=>{
    if(msg.content.startsWith(prefix + "react")){
        let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle("Reactions Roles")
        .setDescription("React to get a role!")
        .setColor("BLUE")
        msg.channel.send(embed).then(m=> m.react("emoji_id"))
    }
})

bot.on("messageReactionAdd", async (reaction, user)=>{
    if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if (reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();
    if(user.bot) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;
    if(reaction.message.channel.id === "channel_id"){
        if(reaction.emoji.id === "emoji_id"){
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add("role_id")
        }
    }
})

bot.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user)=>{
    if(reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
    if(reaction.partial) await reaction.fetch();

    if(user.bot) return;
    if(!reaction.message.guild) return;

    if(reaction.message.channel.id === "channel_id"){
        if(reaction.emoji.id === "emoji_id"){
            await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.remove("role_id")
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Just for clarification. When you restart your bot, do you expect it to react to the older messages and apply the roles, or does it not react to new messages?

Comment: @MagnusVestergaard No, I want the bot to react to the old message and add the role. It'd be awkward to send a new message when I restart the bot. It should do its job to the old message.

Comment: The problem is that your code only registers new messages/reactions, therefore you'll have to add some code that scans through messages that have already been sent and check for the reactions of those. I'll see if I remember to make an answer with some sample code when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make your bot check if previous messages have been reacted upon you could use a code similar to this

```
let guildID = "xxx";
let channelID = "xxx";
let emojiID = "xxx";
let roleID = "xxx";


bot.on("ready", async () => {

    let guild = bot.guilds.cache.find(guild => guild.id == guildID);
    let channel = await guild.channels.cache.find(ch => ch.id == channelID)

    // You can set any limit you want, for performance I used a low number
    channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 })
        .then(async messages => {
            messages.forEach(async message => {

                if (message.partial) await message.fetch();
                if (!message.guild) return;

                for (let reactionObj of message.reactions.cache) {
                    for (let reaction of reactionObj) {
                        if (typeof reaction == "string") continue;
                        if (reaction.emoji.id != emojiID) continue;
                        reaction.users.fetch()
                            .then(async users => {
                                users.forEach(async user => {
                                    if (user.bot) return;
                                    console.log("Adding role")
                                    await reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add(roleID)
                                })
                            })
                    }
                }

            });
        })
        .catch(console.error);
});
```

You might want to make some changes, but this works.

To break it down...

1. Get messages in a specific channel (or multiple)
2. Check if the message has reactions
3. Check if any of the reactions match a specific emoji
4. Add the role to the guild member
5. Optionally check if the member already has the role before attempted to add it

Please note that this code might very well not be the most efficient, but it gets the job done. Also, it does **NOT** work with "non-custom" emojis, for that you'll have to check for emoji.name instead of emoji.id.

As suggested by @michael.grigoryan it is very recommended to check out the documentation.

*Edit: Removed previous answer, to remove confusion*

Answer (score 2):

I just ran into this same issue and have fixed it. Your exact use case is explained deeply here on the docs, though I'll go into a small explanation as well: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#listening-for-reactions-on-old-messages

DiscordJS has a "cache" which it uses to speed up queries (i.e. whenever a user sends a message, DiscordJS keeps it locally -- it saves up to a certain number of recent messages, I believe 100). So when you listen for reactions, discordJS will only listen to the cached ones basically (at least from my understanding). To get it to listen to non-cached messages, you have to use "Partials" which is exactly what it sounds like -- partials of complete objects. This means that you would get only an object with an ID rather than the complete MessageReaction/User object (there's a function on them called `fetch()` which will allow you to get the complete object though). Using Partials will allow you to listen for reactions on old un-cached messages.

To use Partials, create the client like this:

```
const bot = new Client({
  partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'USER', 'REACTION'],
});
```

and be wary later on when you listen for things like `messageReactionAdd`! You'll to do something along the lines of this:

```
client.on(
  'messageReactionAdd',
  async (potentialPartialReaction, potentialPartialUser) => {
    try {
      const reaction = await potentialPartialReaction.fetch();
      const user = await potentialPartialUser.fetch();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }

    // can use reaction and user here!
});
```

I believe that should work in your case but let me know if it doesn't. This worked for me in DiscordJS v12.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some testing and i found something quite strange.

When you restart the bot and try to react to a message sent before the bot was restarted, the bot wont register the reaction. But if you send a new message and react to it the bot will suddenly start registering reactions on all messages.

I think it has something to do with partials but I'm not an expert there!